# What is the point of "throw"?

Tags: javascript, debugging, throw

I ask because whenever I throw an error, it makes the console exit immediately and I can't tell whether one of my exceptions was thrown or it was some other runtime error.  Is this some kind of setting I have for my cmd console where it exits on an exception and it can be changed?  Or is this just how it is?  If so what's the point of "throw" then?

EDIT:

For the curious, I was using throws like this... which I see now is not in line with their intended use:

```
if (array.length !== 28)
            throw 'replacedData.txt in mls_num_' + index + ' FAILED: has ' + array.length + ' values instead of 27'
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: There's only a point to `throw` if somebody is there to `catch`. For more background: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Comment: I assume you mean the [`throw` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) which is used to throw exceptions for try-catch statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing is intended if you have multiple `try` and `catch` blocks nested.  If you catch an error in the innermost try block, you can rethrow it to an outer one.  This can be useful if you identify a fairly generic error and want to throw it as a more specific one, for example.

Comment: Ah so it's not intended to be used as a way to output the error to the console... I see now.  Thanks.